# C# TCP Socket Stream read wrong bytes

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, stream

I Read Stream with:

```
private Stream _Stream;
private Socket _Socket;//TCP Socket

private void ReadStream()
{
    if (Guest)
    {
        var sizeBuffer = ReadBytes(2);//the size buffer is always 2 
        int size = sizeBuffer[1];
        size |= (sizeBuffer[0] << 8);

        var data = ReadBytes(size);

        string payload = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, data.Length);
        var tokens = SplitPayload(payload);

        if (tokens[0] == "nick")
        {
            SetNick(tokens);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Set your nick first");
        }
    }
    else if(!Guest)
    {
        var sizeBuffer = ReadBytes(2);
        int size = sizeBuffer[1];
        size |= (sizeBuffer[0] << 8);

        var data = ReadBytes(size);

        string payload = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, data.Length);
        var tokens = SplitPayload(payload);

        CheckToken(tokens);
    }

    if (encrypted == null)
    {
        encrypted = false;
        byte[] sizebuffer = new byte[2];
        var size = _Socket.Receive(sizebuffer);
        byte[] data = new byte[size];
        var datasize = _Socket.Receive(data);
        if (data[0] == 0x01)
        {
            encrypted = true;
            _Stream = new NetworkStream(_Socket, true);
            var sslStream = new SslStream(_Stream, false);
            serverCertificate = new X509Certificate2(Path, "");
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate);
            _Stream = sslStream;
        }
        else
        {
            encrypted = false;
            _Stream = new NetworkStream(_Socket, true);
        }
    }
}
```

I write to the stream with:

```
private void SendServerMsg(string[] arguments)
{
    var msg = string.Join("\0", arguments);
    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);
    byte[] sizeinfo = new byte[2];

    sizeinfo[1] = (byte)data.Length;
    sizeinfo[0] = (byte)(data.Length >> 8);

    _Stream.Write(sizeinfo, 0, sizeinfo.Length);
    _Stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

my Problem is now: 
1. When I make a Breakpoint at the line

```
_Stream.Write(sizeinfo, 0, sizeinfo.Length);
```

and step through manualy all work. The TCP _Socket gets the correct bytes,
but with no breakpoint the server stucks in the line

```
var data = ReadBytes(size);
```

and the size is more than 5000 but I send not more than 15 bytes (for example: "nick\0test")

hear is the readBytes method

```
private byte[] ReadBytes(int count)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[count];
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var oneByte = _Stream.ReadByte();
        if (oneByte == -1)
        {
            break;
        }

        buffer[i] = (byte)oneByte;
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: How do you know the number of bytes to read?  When sending a message you must give enough info to receiver to detect end of message.  Usually use one of following 3 methods 1) Ascii : End message with know character not part of message 2) Ascii or Binary : precede message with a byte count 3) Ascii or Binary : Fixed length messages.  You can use one or more of these methods as required.

Comment: Can you show ReadBytes method. I can see that in first two bytes you store the length of payload.

Comment: for each message I send 2 packages the first is always 2 bytes long and the value of this package is my length of the real data

Comment: I edited the ReadBytes method

Comment: First of all, why do you read in loop byte by byte? Why don't use [NetworkStream.Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read(v=vs.110).aspx) with preallocated buffer for storing read data? Second of all - you read more than expected, probably, because you get wrong value in the count. You should have an agreement between client and server what is the order of bytes in your data - Big Endian or Little Endian.

Comment: but why is it working when I step through the program in Debug mode manualy with F10/F11

Comment: and I have the Big Endian or Little Endian with "sizeinfo[1] = (byte)data.Length;          
sizeinfo[0] = (byte)(data.Length >> 8);"

Comment: I found the problem I read 2 bytes but the size package was only 1 then the index of read one Byte was wrong and the size package got the first byte of the data.


Thanks for helping me